# Is there a way to automatically backup skype chat in the gmail account for Macs?

Tags: gmail, skype

I would like my skype chat history to be searchable through my gmail account, hence my question is if there are any apps similar to www.g-recorder.com that would work on OSX?

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in this as well and [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com) answered me through email that they are on the way to Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

[G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com) released [MAC version](http://g-recorder.com/for-mac-users-en/). Please note that Skype API has a problem on MAC Lion that we cannot workaround. So our team and lots of our MAC users wait for fix from Skype team.

And yeah, you already noted, I'm one of G-Recorder developers.

[EDIT]: Skype released beta that fixes Lion problem